# When are positive elements mapped to $1$ by same pure states

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a unital C*-algebra, and $0\leq a\leq b\in\mathcal{A}$ be 2 positive elements with unit length, $\|a\|=\|b\|=1$. Show $\|b-(1-a)\|=1$.

I'm trying to prove by finding a pure state $f$ such that $f(a)=f(b)=1$. Does it always exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get it for free. Just let $f$ be a pure state with $f(a)=1$. Since
$$
0\leq a\leq b\leq 1, 
$$
you get
$$
1=f(a)\leq f(b)\leq f(1)=1. 
$$
So $f(b)=1$.

Comment: And the existence of $f$ can just cite Murphy's book Theorem 5.1.11?

Comment: Yep. $ \ \ \ \ $